# Find and delete all directories that do NOT contain certain file types

Tags: linux, bash, find

Here is what I have so far, it works but it throws an error and I am not exactly sure why:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}" | egrep -i -q "\.(mp4|avi|mkv)"' \; -print -exec rm -r {} \;
./test
find: `./test': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I suggest you to be VERY carefull when working with automated file delete function. First, try only to print the file name, then, when fully tested, add the rm command.

Comment: are you expecting that the complete pipeline is being `-exec`d for the value of `{}`? I don't think that is right. I would put all of that code into a shell script  and use `find ... | xargs ./myShellscript.sh ` . AND test, test, test before running! Just have it echo the `rm` cmds, and once they look right pipe those to \ `| bash`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command
`find . -mindepth 1 -type f | egrep -v "\.(mp4|avi|mkv)$" | xargs rm -i`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}" | egrep -i -q "\.(mp4|avi|mkv)"' \; -print | while read line;do rm -r $line;done
```

I wanted to have a one liner that didn't throw an error if no directories matching the regex existed.